# Cannot invoke org.herac.tuxguitar.action.TGActionContext.setAttribute

Tags: guitar

It gave me this error from tuxguitar on linux, after a disk space error:

> Cannot invoke
> "org.herac.tuxguitar.action.TGActionContext.setAttribute(String,
> Object)" because "actionContext" is null

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved it by deleting the folder ".tuxguitar-1.5.4" from my home